# Troubleshooting "failed to load external entity" when loading Symfony 2 app

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to start a new project with symfony 2 but I've some problem.

When i'm going to /web/app_dev.php I've this error :

```
InvalidArgumentException: [WARNING 1549] failed to load external entity 
"file://///INFO/WWW/perso/2011-2012/gdesbiey/Musique/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd" 
(in n/a - line 0, column 0)
[WARNING 3084] Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': 
Failed to locate a schema at location 
'file://///INFO/WWW/perso/2011-2012/gdesbiey/Musique/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd'. 
Skipping the import. (in in_memory_buffer - line 8, column 0)
[ERROR 1845] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}container': 
No matching global declaration available for the validation root. (in //INFO/WWW/perso/2011-2012/gdesbiey/Musique/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/web.xml - line 5, column 0)
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Would you mind adding what you did (like is this the standard installation, with or without vendors, what did you change) as well as your setup (windows/linux, which webserver)? If you got any other information (webserver logs, symfony logs), please provide them as well.

Comment: it's the standard installation with vendors.
The system is : Windows NT INFO-TIMIDE 6.1 build 7601 (Unknow Windows version Standard Edition Service Pack 1) i586 .
All details about phpinfo() are on : http://info-timide.iut.u-bordeaux1.fr/2011-2012/gdesbiey/Musique/

THanks

Comment: Does the installation pass all criteria on the check page located at `http://localhost/Symfony/web/config.php` (or whichever path will take you to `web/config.php` for your setup).

Comment: Only 1 major problem : "Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).
"

Answer (score 1):

You probably should clear symfony's cache, even manually, because it keeps sometimes references to resources you might have set in your config files in the past. I had the same kind of error for a translation yaml file which had been deleted, and that solved my problem.

```
php app/console cache:clear --no-debug

rm -Rf app/cache/*
rm -RF app/logs/*
```

You'll may have to set up permissions on these folders. There's a note explaining how to do that in [Installing and Configuring Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup).

Answer (score 0):

The xsd file cannot be written to disk .. it is likely a mish-mash of backwards ("\") and forwards ("/") slashes along with file handlers/streams beginning with "file://" and mixing the drive in "C:\" and then things being str_replace()'ed with useless nonsense like more slashes.

Take a look at your path:

"file://///INFO/WWW/perso/2011-2012/gdesbiey/Musique/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd"

Open this up in a shell/console and `dir` yourself to the end of the file path.